# manipulating dynamically created form elements without losing their values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do a search and replace on a complex bit of dynamically created form. It's as simple as finding all the instances of one string and replacing them with another, made more complicated by the fact there are 11 instances per bit of form and make up only parts of various attributes.

Examples of the kind of thing I'm working with (it's the '001' bit I'm searching and replacing):

```
<div id="step_title:001|title">
<label for="step_title:001|title|field">
<input id="step_title:001|title|field" name="step_title:001|title|field"/>
```

I had thought something like this would do the trick:

```
$(this).html($(this).html().replace('old string', 'new string'));
```

However because the bit of form is dynamically added the form data is lost every time I perform this action. I tried using the .clone() function which seems to preserve the data, but that doesn't allow you to manipulate the object. I also tried performing the search and replace directly onto the containing object, but I guess .replace() only works on strings.

Comment: using the .live() function should solve this

Comment: The function is called using onclick, so I'm not sure where the .live() would go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just update the attributes instead?

```
$('div, label, input').each(
    function() {
        var _this = $(this);
        _this.attr('id', _this.attr('id').replace('old string', 'new string'));
        _this.attr('for', _this.attr('id').replace('old string', 'new string'));
        _this.attr('name', _this.attr('id').replace('old string', 'new string'));
    }
);
```

Might be a bit longwinded...

Comment: OK, so after some unrelated issues due to bad caharcters (bar and colon), I've got this to work. The problem is that it doesn't deal well with the name and for attributes, if the node doesn't have them it fails. I've added checks to see if they exist which solves this problem.

Comment: Yeah sorry, this was untested and was just an idea/pointer i.e. I hadn't added error checking. Glad it was useful all the same :)